# Character has an eyrie from which the exit is a very long almost vertical chute

Tags: story-identification, books

A sci fi book I loved as a child in early to mid 1970s. 
Can’t remember much about it, but the memory of a main (male) character having an eyrie (or eerie) high up from which the regular way down was a lengthy near-vertical chute/slide. I seem to remember a climactic scene taking place there. 
Possibly space/other planet type of setting. The character may be the chief of a spacestation of some kind.
Could’ve been Brian Aldiss but quite possibly not!
I would love to find it as the atmosphere and excitement have stayed with me, while all narrative and plot has escaped me.

Comment: Do you know any details for certain which would suggest this is a work of science fiction? Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if you can [edit] in any more details.

Comment: It's not the [Moon Door](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Moon_Door) is it?

Comment: It's not the Moon Door, thanks.

Comment: There's a long slide like that *into* the shelter in the very beginning of *Emergence* by David R. Palmer, but it's roundly ten years too late -- published 1984.

Comment: Sheffield also has Asperian escape in a long precipitous chute from the Greasers(?) in one of the *Trader* stories, but that's also a decade too late.